# UILabel смена текста каждые 3 секунды

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть таблица, ячейки которой содержат по одному UILabel.
Я пытаюсь научить UILabel менять текст по требованию. Для этого написал вот такой класс:

```
@interface HSIntervalLabel ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isFirstTextShowed;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *firstText;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *secondText;

@end

@implementation HSIntervalLabel

- (void)prepare
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeText:) name:NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL_LABEL_SHOULD_CHANGE_TEXT object:nil];
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self prepare];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self prepare];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self prepare];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)firstText beforeText:(NSString *)secondText
{
    self.firstText = firstText;
    self.secondText = secondText;
    self.text = firstText;
    self.isFirstTextShowed = YES;
}

- (void)changeText:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (self.isFirstTextShowed) {
        self.text = self.secondText;
        self.isFirstTextShowed = NO;
    }
    else {
        self.text = self.firstText;
        self.isFirstTextShowed = YES;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

@end
```

Но текст почему-то не меняется, хотя, если смотреть в дебаггере, то все меняется.
Сами сообщения в NSNotificationCenter посылаются с помощью NSTimer:

```
dispatch_once(&kOnlyOnce, ^{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(preparePostingNotificationsForIntervalLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
});
```

Comment: Вот проект на похожую тему: [TOMSMorphingLabel](https://github.com/TomKnig/TOMSMorphingLabel).

Answer (score 1):

текст то вы поменяли, но вам надо еще перерисовать вьюшки либо так     [self.tableView reloadData]  
либо если вьюшку сами рисуете то setNeedsDisplay

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте во время брекпоинте, где вы сетите текст, в каком потоке вы находитесь? Так как с графикой можно работать только в главном потоке main. Все остальное называется можно грубо назвать offscreen-rendering. Если это так, что у вас не тот поток, просто передайте управление UI в мэейн поток, удобным способом.

Я, к стати, тоже не вижу где вы лейблу текст меняете?